# How to set ThreadPoolTaskExecutor if sending numerous http requests at same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

In my case, I need to send over million of http requests to client's app for popping notification. like below sudo code

```
int numOfHttpReq = 1000000;
for (int i = 0; i < numOfHttpReq; i++) {
  call async method with ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ...
}
```

I have referenced article from this [website](https://engineering.zalando.com/posts/2019/04/how-to-set-an-ideal-thread-pool-size.html), and obtain a formula

> Number of threads = Number of Available Cores * (1 + Wait time / Service time)

However, I think it's not 100% suitable in my case. I'd like to know how to set ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in this case such as CorePoolSize, MaxPoolSize, QueueCapacity, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you take a look at the "Gatling" tool for these kind of performance related tests. You dont worry about the object pooling and other stuffs just feed then whats your use-case like within the span of time how many concurrent requests / concurrent users / ....other options as well there.
[Gatling](https://gatling.io/)

Comment: Thanks your advice. Do you mean it's not necessary to use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Comment: Yes, you dont worry about the threadpool related stuffs, which will handled internally by gatling. You just write your rest call in it and configure it with how many number of requests / how many number of users concurrent access / if interval is required then that as well. Just checkout its docs its pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty well do this by simply using the constructor provided by ThreadPoolExecutor.

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
        int maximumPoolSize,
        long keepAliveTime,
        TimeUnit unit,
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
            this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
                    Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
        }
```

And you can use worker thread to call the HttpRequest.